# How to implement a Heaviside function in an ODE in R

Tags: r, ode

What's the proper way to implement a Heaviside step function that's part of an `deSolve` ODE?

My first guess would be to use `ifelse` s.t.

```
ode <- function(t, y, p) {
  dy = numeric(1)

  H = ifelse((y[1] - 1) >= 0, 1, 0)

  dy[1] = -p*y[1] + (y[1] - 1)*H

  list(dy)
}
```

Is that the proper way to do it or should I use the `events` option in `deSolve` by using a root function? As far as I understood it, Matlab would need me to use a root function and split the integration.

Comment: In my opinion it's ok. It works as expected ...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I reimplemented my model in Mathematica and used the `HeavisideTheta` function and the results are the same.